# li elements to justify

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to justify variable number of `li` elements, to fill the width of a `ul` block with equal spacing between them. It would be important to have minimal distance between the elements.
I tried various solutions from StackOverflow answers, for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/10020586/3897243, but none of them worked out for me.

HTML:

```
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="/projektek/covenantal-cathexion/">Covenantal</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/projektek/inyoite-unstintingly/">Inyoite</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/projektek/myopical-gaspingly/">Myopical</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/projektek/funiculate-periarthritis/">Funiculate</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/projektek/uncompromisingness-mastatrophia/">Uncompromisingness</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul::after {
    width: 100%; 
    display: inline-block; 
    content: "."; 
    visibility: hidden
}
li {
    display: inline-block
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r1mw5j9h/

Comment: You justify text, not elements

Comment: All you need is just the `li` selector only, with `padding-left` property. There is no need to `float` property in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `display:table; width:100%;` on your wrapping `<ul>` and `display:table-cell; text-align:center;` on the `<li>` will ensure that all elements will fit side by side using the minimum available width and will split the available padding evenly when there is more space to give.

See your updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/r1mw5j9h/2/

Answer (score 0):

if you want space between each elements then try setting

```
li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
background-color: #aaa;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 1.5;
padding:5px; // try adding padding 
}
```

padding property will give you space between elements. 
is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul, li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul {
    background-color: #888;
    text-align: center;
}
ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #aaa;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
ul > li a{
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="/projektek/covenantal-cathexion/">Covenantal</a>    
    <li><a href="/projektek/inyoite-unstintingly/">Inyoite</a>    
    <li><a href="/projektek/unpollutable-unicameralist/">Unpollutable</a>   
    <li><a href="/projektek/bibliopolical-reimpel/">Bibliopolical</a>    
    <li><a href="/projektek/vibrato-myotacismus/">Vibrato</a>   
    <li><a href="/projektek/myopical-gaspingly/">Myopical</a>   
    <li><a href="/projektek/funiculate-periarthritis/">Funiculate</a>   
    <li><a href="/projektek/indesignate-parachromoparous/">Indesignate</a>    
    <li><a href="/projektek/uncompromisingness-mastatrophia/">Uncompromisingness</a>   
</ul>
```